# Finding specific repeated digits in a number

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that will count the number of `5`s in a number and display it.  So if the user enters:

```
52315
```

Then the program should ouptut:

```
Yes, there are '5's and they're 2
```

Here is my code but there is something wrong with it.

```
{
    int n,m;
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Enter an: ";
    cin >> n;

    int *arr;
    arr = new int[count];

    // Getting digits from number
    while (n > 0)
    {
        count++; 
        m = n%10;  
        n = n/10;

    //Trying to put every digit in an array

        for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i];
            arr[i] = m;
            cout << arr[i];
        }
        int even = 5;
    //Trying to see if there's a digit 5 in inputed number and how many if so.
        for (int j = 0; j<count; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j]==even)
            {
                cout << "Yes, there's a digit '5' " << endl;
                s++;
            }
        }



        cout << "Count of '5's : " << even;
        delete[] arr;
    }



     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is terribly wrong first of all? You have to be precise and explain what is the expected output ( you did that ) but also what is the actual output that you get. I'm guessing that the creation of your array is not good at all to begin with.

Comment: You want to use the `%` operator in combination with `/` and you don't actually need the array. (And calling 5 "even" is a bit strange.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Changed code lil bit, can u see what's wrong now?

Comment: @Maartin1996 After the user has input a number, you're waiting for the user to input it again, but digit by digit the second time.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
}
```

You're trying to populate the array with the another user input rather than the existing one.

You also can do it without the array:

```
int count = 0;
int n;
cin >> n;

do {
    if (n%10 ==5) count++;
    n /= 10;
} while (n);

cout << "Count of '5's : " << count;
```

Comment: There're no errors, but when I input 151, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for every number.
If you only want to know a special number like 5, just remove the for-loop and print count[theNumberYouWantToKnow].

```
#define BASE 10

void output() {
    int givenNumber;

    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> givenNumber;

    int count[BASE] = { 0 };

    while(givenNumber > 0) {
        int digit = givenNumber % BASE;
        givenNumber /= BASE;
        count[digit]++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < BASE; i++) {
        cout << "Found the number " << i << " " << count[i] << " times." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `base` could be a const so that `count` could be an array.